# How to expand a 2d image to 3d in autocad?

Tags: render, autocad

I am trying to design a solid 3d surface of an airfoil"NACA 0009" using Autocad 2010 ,firstly I draw it using spline command and put all the points from an txt file then I used Push/pull command to make a replica to make a solid surface ,as can be seen in image.But i am having doubt that how to connect the section on the Leading edge .Can anyone please help me .

How to convert this surface into 3d model 
[image: air]

Comment: Have you tried using the EXTRUDE command? I'm not 100% sure that is even in AutoCAD 2010.

Comment: I think I used it but the leading edge doesnt joined

Comment: I would suggest you repost on the AutoCAD end-user forum: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad/ct-p/8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about computer programming.